# How can I set values higher then

Tags: mysql

I have a task in MySql where I must to set up value that are not less then 2600:
Below you can find my code

```
create table POSITIONS(
POS_NAME varchar(20),
SALARY_FROM float NOT NULL,
SALARY_TO float NOT NULL,
primary key(POS_NAME));
```

Comment: Add according CHECK constraint.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint-emulation/